# Compensating for laggy positive feedback

Tags: optimization, controller, automation

I'm trying to make a program run as accurately as possible while staying at a fixed frame rate. How do you do this?

Formally, I have some parameter `b` in `[0,1]` that I can set to determine how accurate my computations are (where 0 is least accurate, 0.5 is fairly accurate, and 1 is very accurate). The higher this is, the lower frame rate I will get.

However, there is a "lag", where after changing this parameter, the frame rate won't change until `d` milliseconds afterwards, where `d` can vary and is unknown.

Is there a way to change this parameter in a way that prevents "wiggling"? The problem is that if I am experiencing a low frame rate, if I increase the parameter then measure again, it will only be slightly higher, so I will need to increase it more, and then the framerate will be too slow, so I need to decrease the parameter, and I get this oscillating behavior. Is there a way to prevent this? I need to be as reactive as possible in doing this, because changing too slowly will cause the framerate to be incorrect for too long.

Comment: Any particular hardware?  OS?  Language?  *Any* details?

Comment: You might try to integrate the values (sum together) from a longer period and divide by number of measurements and use that value to determine direction of adjustment

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't think it should really matter as this is a fairly general problem. If needed, I am working in Windows,C#, my processing is on the graphics card (in a compute shader), and I am doing raycasting in real time. I need to change the amount of steps that each ray takes based on how long each frame takes (I have a way to measure the graphics cards' latency), but I am doing this in VR so I need to prevent lag as much as possible. Yet, depending on where they are in a scene the ray casting might be more or less expensive, which is why b  needs to adapt with the changing frame rate.

Comment: @TeroTolonen Yea I was trying that (a running mean, I even played with a running variance as well), but the problem was that the frame rate is changing too much that either: 1. That method doesn't react quick enough if there is too many samples, or 2. That method does too much oscillation if there is too few samples. The sweet spot between these two also seems to change with time, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an adaptive feedback dampener. Trying an electrical circuit analogy :)

I'd first try to get more info about how the circuit's input signal and responsiveness look like. So I'd first make the algorithm update `b` **not** with the desired values but with the previous values plus or minus (as needed towards the desired value) a small fixed increment, say `.01` instead (ignore the sloppy response time for now). While doing so I'd collect and plot/analyze the "desired" `b` values, looking for:

- the general shape of the changes: smooth or rather "steppy" or "spiky"? (spiky would require a stronger dampening to prevent oscillations, steppy would require a weaker dampening to prevent lagging)
- the maximum/typical/minimum changes in values from sample to sample
- the distribution of the changes in values from sample to sample (I'd plan the algorithm to react best for changes in a typical range, say 20-80% range and consider acceptable lagging for changes higher than that or oscillations for values lower than that)

The end goal is to be able to obtain parameters for operating alternatively in 2 modes:

- a `high-speed tracking` mode (also the system's initial mode)
- a `normal tracking` mode

In `high-speed tracking` mode the `b` value updates can be either:

- not dampened - the update value is the full desired value - **only if** the changes shape is **not** spiky **and only** in the 1st `b` update after entering the `high-speed tracking` mode. This would help reduce lagging.
- dampened - the update delta is just a fraction (dampening factor) of the desired delta and reflects the fact that the effect of the previous `b` value update might not be completely reflected in the current frame rate due to `d`. Dampening helps preventing oscillations at the expense of potentially increasing lag (always conflicting requirements). The dampening factor would be higher for a smooth shape and smaller for a spiky shape.

Switching from `high-speed tracking` mode to `normal tracking` mode can be done when the delta between `b`'s previous value and its desired value falls below a certain `mode change threshold value` (eventually maintained for a minimum number of consecutive samples). The `mode change threshold value` would be initially estimated from the info collected above and/or empirically determined.

In `normal tracking` mode the delta between `b`'s previous value and its desired value remain below the `mode change threshold value` and is either ignored (no `b` update) or and update is made either with the desired value or some average one - tiny course corrections, keeping the frame rate practically constant, no dampening, no lagging, no oscillations.

When in `normal tracking` mode the delta between `b`'s previous value and its desired value goes above the `mode change threshold value` the system switches again to the `high-speed tracking` mode.

I would also try to get a general idea about how the `d` response time looks like. To do that I'd change the algorithm to only update `b` with the desired values **not** at every iteration, but every `n` iterations apart (maybe even re-try for several `n` values). This should indicate how many sample periods would generally a `b` value change take to become fully effective and should be reflected in the dampening factor: the longer it takes for a change to take effect the stronger the dampening should be to prevent oscillations.

Of course, this is just the general idea, a lot of experimental trial/adjustment iterations may be required to reach a satisfactory solution.